# How to access object Property inside the controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I wanted to know how to access and store a property of a gotten object in laravel controller and here is my code:-

```
 $phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->get();
    $test = $phonebooks->id;
    return view('admin.phonebooks.index', compact('phonebooks'))->with('current_time',$current_time);
```

Here I want to store the id property in `$test` variable but I get this error:- `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: You are using `get()` method not `first()`

Comment: `->get();` would return a collection of objects, use `->first()` or `$test = $phonebooks[0]->id;` or a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Its a collection

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();

then $userId = $users->id // this will always throw error
```

instead try doing this

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    dd($user->id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->get();` This return instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. 
For this case use

```
foreach ($phonebooks as $phonebook) {
    $test = $phonebook->id;
}
```

Or you must be get only one recorde in db using

```
$phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->first(); // if need some condition
$test = $phonebook->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

`$phonebooks`  is variable type of collection
so you must acces each phonebook with foreach or just index.
with foreach :

```
$i = 0;
foreach($phonebooks as $phonebook){
    $test[$i] = $phonebook->id;
    $i++;
}
```

or with defined index:

```
$test = $phonebooks[0]->id;
```